# How do I Split contents of a directory into multiple sub directories in alphabetical order?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, filemanager, linux-headers

```
ls -1 | wc -l

read -p 'How Many Directories: ' F;
read -p 'Sub-Directories Prefix: ' S;

PARRENT=${PWD}
# cd $PARRENT 
n=0
for i in *
do
  if [ $((n+=1)) -gt $F ]; then
    n=1
  fi
  todir=$PARRENT/"$S"_$n
  [ -d "$todir" ] || mkdir "$todir" 
  mv "$i" "$todir" 
done
```

When I use this code the order of the file is always random. I would like for my files to have other .

Comment: Explain what you have and what you want to get by editing your question. Give an example.

Comment: see the `sort` command, then see `ls -1 | sort`, then replace your `for i in *` statement with `for i in ${ls -1 | sort}`

Comment: cant see why it should be important to create dir in order, as soon  as something change in a directory the timestamps will get updated

Comment: I think the issue is that the OP's code implements a "round robin" move whereas presumably they want to move the first *n/F* files into one directory, then the next *n/F* files into the second directory and so on

Comment: @Alex Jean Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you further elaborate from your example what files you would like to have ordered?